# SKMapsInitializationException Skobbler?

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am using from sample of [skobbler](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) android studio.

When I click on the link of map (Powered by Scout| OSM) I redirect to web browser but when I back crash me!!!

What can I do ?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{........activity.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:19)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
            at com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:19) 
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: com.skobbler.ngx.SKMapsInitializationException: SKMaps was not initialized. In order to initialize it, please call: SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(context, mapInitSettings)
            at com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder.<init>(SourceFile:144)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
            at com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:19) 
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039) 
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is happening because at the time the map fragment is requested to be inflated the SKMaps library is not initialized.

Workarounds to the problem, try them in this order:

1. Make sure the phone's developer option `Do not keep activities` is not checked.
2. Check whether the library is initialized before inflating the map fragment and if it is not reinitialize it.
3. Stop calling the `SKMaps.getInstance().destroySKMaps();`